# How to display timestamps within a topic on Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, latency

i am looking for a way to display a timestamp of each message within a certain topic in Apache Kafka, is there a way to do it?

My infrastructure looks like this:

I have built an MQTT client that sends pseudo temperature data to the Mosquitto MQTT broker which then forwards it to Apache Kafka.

What I am trying to do is to build a cloud-(edge)fog like environment with Apache Kafka running in the cloud and MQTT broker running locally. The idea is to measure the latencies.

How much time it takes for message to arrive on the MQTT and then on Kafka. Now I can set the timestamp in my MQTT client and on the MQTT easily but I still haven't found a way to display timestamp of messages within Kafka topic and that's what I would need in order to calculate the latency.

Any ideas?

Comment: Producer can set the timestamp in message record or Kafka broker can set creation time if not set by user, then same timestamp can be retrieved from consumer. reference:https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html

Comment: hey thank you for your reply. The problem with this is, that i have used python (pykafka to be precise) and not Kafka native Java.

Answer (score 1):

When you consume a Kafka record in any client, the records have timestamp attributes on them (only for Kafka versions 0.10.2+, when timestamps became part of the protocol)

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean. I dont really use Kafka records in the client. I just have an application that generates pseudo data (temperature between 21 and 24 deegres), then sends this data to the MQTT and from there on this data is delegated to a particular Kafka topic. What i would need is a way to capture the timestamp of when data has arrived on the Kafka broker or particular topic. This way, i can measure the starting time (generation of the message), the time it arrived on the MQTT broker and lastly the time that it arrived on the Kafka broker.

Comment: What exactly is "delegating" the data? Kafka Connect? That's adding timestamps to the kafka records, which you can consume and inspect. Note: pykafka is no longer maintained. You can look at the kafka-python documentation for how to get record timestamps

Comment: @mirakuru970 you have to check for active python client which is being updated regularly. I see only confluent-kafka-python is more active, also has timestamp attribute. python client list: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-Python

Comment: The python application (bridge) is delegating the data. It just writes the data to the Kafka topic that must be created prior to running the program.

Comment: @mirakuru970 Again, I'm not familiar with pykafka, but see `timestamp_ms` in the KafkaProducer of kafka-python, if you want to control the record time from the producer itself. Otherwise, it's automatically inserted when you call the send function, and should be consumable from any modern Kafka client https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html#kafka.KafkaProducer.send More specifically, to your first comment, you must consume _records_ to get any time information. There's no external tooling to do what you're asking

Comment: i dont think we understand each other (it might be because i have hard time explaining what i want xd). I have now switched from pykafka library to kafka-python library like u suggested. What i need is just a way to get timestamps of when the messages that i am consuming arrived on the Kafka broker (or in the topic if you will). I consume the messages with consumer = KafkaConsumer('temperature2')
for message in consumer:
    print(json.loads(message.value))
This doesnt get me the timestamp of the messages that i talked about previously.

Comment: Well, did you try `message.timestamp` instead of `message.value`?

Comment: could it be that message.timestamp actually gets the timestamp of when the message has been transmitted to Kafka and not when the message has been received?

Comment: It should be when the producer initially created the message, not when the broker got it, or when the consumer received it. If you want when the consumer reads the message, you can simply use `time.now()`. There is no direct way to see when the broker got the record, AFAIK

Comment: hey man, ye that actually makes sense and now it is working the way it is supposed to. Thank you very much, you helped me out a lot!

Comment: Hey man, do you know exactly what time does message.timestamp actually sample. I can't seem to find the answer to this and the measurements i am getting are weird.

Comment: Please re-read [last comment from May 16th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076712/how-to-display-timestamps-within-a-topic-on-apache-kafka/72077472?noredirect=1#comment127671652_72077472)